# How to import csv file to postgresql table without using copy command

Tags: sql, ruby, postgresql

I am planning to use insert command or anything like bulk insert but not copy command . please help!

Comment: Why you don't want to use the copy command? Is it a school homework?

Comment: nope mate . just asking if there is a way . 
If you want help otherwise just leave it. @TommasoDiBucchianico

Comment: you can modify your csv to become a list of inserts. If you want to "import" csv - copy is the meant way.

Comment: Your question isn't a good fit as asked. On Stack Overflow we want to see what you tried, then we'll help solve a specific problem. Your question is very broad. Please read "[ask]" and the linked pages, and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users

Comment: There are multiple ways to read a CSV file, however the built-in CSV class is a good starting point. To insert the records you can generate insert statements, or use the pg gem, or an ORM like Sequel, Active Record or DataMapper. You need to research how those work, try writing code, then ask a specific question about a specific problem. The CSV class has good examples as does Sequel's README and cheatsheet pages.

Answer (score 1):

You tagged your question with `ruby`, so a ruby'ish way could be:

Install the `smarter_csv` gem (https://github.com/tilo/smarter_csv) which lets you parse each line into a hash where the column title is used as the key.

```
inserts = SmarterCSV.process('/path/to/file.csv')
# [
#   { col_name: "value from row 1", ... },
#   { col_name: "value from row 2", ... }
# ]
```

Then you might use whatever ORM or database connector you like, e.g. `ActiveRecord`:

```
MyModel.insert(inserts)
```

Comment: The built-in CSV class can do the same by using the `headers: :first_row` option and `to_hash` on the returned row object.

Comment: Thanks @theTinMan I didn't know that.